# create uvc device and test an application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, uvc

I'm working with a board which has Linux installed. Eventually it will be used as a USB webcam. I built the kernel and added a UVC driver to it.

I'm following [these instructions](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6470812e22261d2342ef1597be62e63a0423d691/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L717-L730) to test it. Unfortunately when I connect my host and run the application, I get the following error:

`v4l2_core: (jpeg decoder) error while decoding frame`

I'd like to test the [application that I'm using](https://github.com/cyboflash/uvc-gadget.git.) on my host machine. There are several issues with that.

On the linux board that I use, when I execute `modrobe g_webcam`, I get a new video device appears in `/dev`, `/dev/video0`. When I execute it on my host, `Linux ubuntu 4.10.0-32-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 9 09:19:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, nothing happens. I google around but I wasn't able to find an answer to why this is happening.

1. So how do I create a video device on linux and bind it to UVC gadget with `g_webcam`?
2. Let's say we figured out step 1. After I execute `uvc-gadget -u /dev/video<uvc video node #> -v /dev/video<vivid video node #>`, how would I read data from the gadget?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> When I execute it [`modprobe g_webcam`] on my host, `Linux ubuntu 4.10.0-32-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 9 09:19:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, nothing happens

That's expected. Your x86_64 host likely doesn't have an OTG UDC, so there is no way to enable a gadget on there. You can check `dmesg` on the host to confirm this, but in any case you shouldn't run `modprobe g_webcam` on the host.

> So how do I create a video device on linux and bind it to UVC gadget with `g_webcam`?

Your `modprobe g_webcam` command created the output video device. When you run `uvc-gadget` it knows to bind to `/dev/video0` as you can tell from the source code.

> After I execute `uvc-gadget -u /dev/video<uvc video node #> -v /dev/video<vivid video node #>`, how would I read data from the gadget?

On the host, first confirm that `/dev/videoX` enumerates properly (run `dmesg`). Next, use a UVC camera viewer such as guvcview: `sudo apt install guvcview`

> Unfortunately when I connect my host and run the application, I get the following error: `v4l2_core: (jpeg decoder) error while decoding frame`

Are you getting that error on the device, rather than the host? I haven't used vivid myself, but unfortunately there's a lot that can go wrong with UVC on both ends. I recommend you isolate problems by first running with synthetic data (`./uvc-gadget -d`) rather than vivid, as well as uncompressed YUYV rather than JPEG (`-f 0`). You could have many debugging steps ahead but this could at least bring you to a starting point where the host can see images streaming.